# Trying to merge two data frames in R gives me the following: <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Tags: r

I am simulating some data and want to create a data set with two different probabilities and then later run a regression on the data so I am encoding the simulations from each "method" with a zero or one. It is all fine and dandy until I try to merge the two data frames. The result has no entries. I have double checked and the column names are the same so I don't understand what is going wrong. Here is the code I am using:

```
library(MASS)
simulate_number <- function(p, theta, lambda, n){
  '
  Simulate_number
  
  Function that simulates data from a binomial distribution where 
  the number of trials are drawn from a negative-binomial distribution.
  
  ### Parameters ###
  p = the probability of succsess in the binomial trial
  
  theta = the theta variable in the negative-binoimial trial
  
  lambda = is the average in the negative-binomial distribution this number is then multiplied by 20 to more accuratly represent the real data.
  
  n = number of simulation runs
  
  ### Returns ###
  A data frame with entries of all the following parameters for each of the n simulations,
  
  '
  lambda = lambda * 20
  p_hat = rep(0, n)
  p_hat_t = rep(0, n)
  Y_20 = rep(0, n)
  m_true = rep(0, n)
  m_actual = rep(0, n)
  for(i in 1:n){
    m_true[i] = rnegbin(1, lambda, theta)
    Y_20[i] = rbinom(1, m_true[i], p)
    m_actual[i] = rnegbin(1, lambda, theta)
    p_hat[i] = Y_20/m_actual[i]
    p_hat_t[i] = Y_20/m_true[i]
  }
  df.p_hat = data.frame(p_hat)
  df.p_hat_t = data.frame(p_hat_t)
  df.Y_20 = data.frame(Y_20)
  df.m_true = data.frame(m_true)
  df.m_actual = data.frame(m_actual)
  result = cbind(df.p_hat, df.p_hat_t, df.m_true, df.m_actual, df.Y_20)
  return(result)
}

simulate_data <- function(p_0, p_1, theta, lambda, n){
  '
  Function that uses the function, simulate_number(p, theta, lambda, n) to create a data set 
  with two theoretical methods and saves them in a data frame with coding 0 and 1 for the two methods respectivly.
  
  ### Parameters ###
  
  p_0 = the probability of a failure to remove a lice for the first method
  
  p_1 = the probability of a failure to remove a lice for the second method
  
  theta = the dispersion parameter for the neg-bin distribution
  
  lambda = the average number of lice on a fish
  
  n = the number of simulations
  
  ### Returns ###
  A data frame with the results from simulate_louse for each method and a code of 0 or 1 denoting what method
  '
  
  code_0 = rep(0, n)
  code_1 = rep(1, n)
  
  method_0 = simulate_number(p_0, theta, lambda, n)
  method_1 = simulate_number(p_1, theta, lambda, n)
  
  method_0 = cbind(method_0, code_0)
  method_1 = cbind(method_1, code_1)
  
  method_0$code_0 = as.factor(method_0$code_0)
  method_1$code_1 = as.factor(method_1$code_1)
  
  names(method_0)[names(method_0) == "code_0"] <- "code"
  names(method_1)[names(method_1) == "code_1"] <- "code"
  
  merged = merge(method_0, method_1)
  
  return(merged)
}

simulate_data(p_0 = .1, p_1 = .3, theta = 10, lambda = 2, n = 250)
```

As mentioned I have tried checking if the column names are different and I have tried doing different variations with as.factor and as.data.frame but to no avail. I hope anyone can help, thank you in advance.

Comment: TL;DR but using `merge` without specifying columns by which to merge might be unintended.

Comment: I did try with specifying that I want to merge by column names but that gave the same result, to be fair I might just not understand how to specify it properly

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that this is the output I am using 'data_simulation = simulate_data(0.1, 0.3, 10, 2, 250)'

Comment: `merge` without specifying `by` columns will give you rows that are identical between both data.frames. Apparently, that's not the case for any rows in your simulation.

Comment: In that case how would I specify that I want to merge by columns? I don't seem to understand it. And in the documentation section it says the following: By default the data frames are merged on the columns with names they both have. Thank you and hope my ignorance is not too much of a bother

Comment: You are right regarding the documentation. But as far as I can see, that's all names in your example. Do you expect the two simulations to produce some identical obervations?

Comment: Could you provide a short example of the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need merge. Instead use rbind(). For example:

```
simulate_data <- function(p_0, p_1, theta, lambda, n){

  method_0 = simulate_number(p_0, theta, lambda, n)
  method_1 = simulate_number(p_1, theta, lambda, n)
  
  method_0$code = rep(0, n)
  method_1$code = rep(1, n)
    
  merged = rbind(method_0, method_1)
  
  return(merged)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked and your code was way prettier than mine. I didn't know you could initiate a column in the data frame by simply saying method$code = ... I did also find out that dplyr package has a function called full_join that also works.